# How to obfuscate angularjs code in www folder of cordova project?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, obfuscation

suggest better tools to do the obfuscation of js file code. I need suggestion to do the same. I dont need jScrambler. Any other solution?

Comment: Need help in best licenced obfuscation tolls except Jscrambler and the process of obfuscation.

Comment: you should use `babel` with `babel-minify` plugin

Comment: https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator

Answer (score 0):

You can use **grunt** and [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify):

module.exports = function (grunt) {

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

grunt.initConfig({        
    /*
     * Minify files
     */
    uglify: {
        options: {
            mangle: false,
            compress: {
                drop_console: true
            }
        },
        my_target: {
            files: [
                {
                    src: 'app/src/**/*.js',
                    dest: 'app/www/myapp.min.js'
                }
          ]
        }
    }

});

grunt.registerTask('minify', ['uglify']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Is there any trusted licence tools for the same?